# slf4j: any way to suppress the NOP error message?

Tags: java, slf4j

If I use slf4j and the classpath doesn't contain a logger implementation, it defaults to a NOP logger operation. That's fine with me. But is there any way to suppress the initial error message?

```
 SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
 SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
 SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways and workarounds to achieve this:

- Add built-in [slf4j-nop](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.6.2/slf4j-nop-1.6.2.jar) binding to your CLASSPATH
- Create your own binding that *truly* does nothing. More work, less hacky.
- Override `System.err` by calling `System.setErr()` with some null implementation of `PrintStream`

Comment: Good answer. I would mention adding slf4j-nop.jar (or any other slf4j-bonding) as first choice.

Comment: You're right, I actually reversed the order of my advices to emphasize the most appropriate one.